# Preprocessing technique in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

Let's assume that we have an XML File.

```
<world>
    <country > 
        <name>INDIA</name>
        <states>#states_count</states> // the place where i need to need to insert.
    </country>
    <country > 
        <name>SRILANKA</name>
        <states>9 states</states>
    </country>
</world>
```

I have a string in C# which contains

```
String states_count  = "29 states";
```

i replaced this by parsing ,travering to the node using XmlDocument and pasting the string to innerxml.

This is not what i need , i need to find "#states_count" token in xml, and replace the "states_count" string using preprocessor technique.

is it possible using preprocessor technique ?

if yes , please help me in this.

Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, no, that's a pretty meaningless approach.  Load the xml file, change the data, save it back.  It doesn't get simpler than that.

Comment: Or use XSLT then there is no C# coding involved.  Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430411/update-the-text-of-an-element-with-xslt-based-on-param

Answer (score 1):

Read your XML file in as a string, do a string replace, load the string as XML with `xmlDoc.LoadXml()` instead of reading the file.